# Is it possible for MinGW g++ to understand the type library of a COM server?

Tags: com, g++, mingw

Since the command-line tools `x86_64-w64-mingw32-widl` on Linux and `widl` on Windows both are able to produce type libraries, the .tlb files, for COM clients to import, it's reasonable to surmise that it might be doable to use MinGW toolset to build a COM client that is able to acquire COM interfaces by using smart pointers offered by the .tlb file, instead of calling function `CoCreateInstance` to get the interfaces. The question is how?

Visual C++ has its nonstandard directive `#import` to introduce the smart pointer types (and other stuff) to C++ code. What is the counterpart when we are using MinGW `g++`?

By the way, I've been googling all day and found it difficult to find useful information about "MinGW + COM". Most of them use Visual C++. If you know somewhere out there a good online tutorial on this topic is, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, MinGW headers are not all up to date (in par with Windows SDK), but beyond that (you can always redefine the missing parts), COM objects can be used by MinGW and associated toolchain. Advanced tooling (such as #import) is a complete different matter.

Comment: @SimonMourier Is it not possible to take advantage of type libraries in a way as simple as #import foo.tlb when using MinGW? What is the plan B you as an expert would suggest? Stick to CoCreateInstance? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any equivalent to #import. If you really want to stick to MinGW toolchain (I personally not recommend it for Windows developments, especially now there's a Visual Studio Community version and Microsoft is much more cross platform aware then it used to be) then yes, you must go with CoCreateInstance et al. If you want smart pointers, you can rewrite an equivalent of _com_ptr_t and others.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you. You saved me a lot of time, not only on this question. I don't have to go through many experiments myself. Really think you. I wish I had some cryto coins so I can buy you a drink. Too bad, I'm currently poor, but I'll remember you until the day I die. Thank you. :)